# Nuclear stripping reaction in $^7\rm Li$

Tags: nuclear-physics

IFMIF  neutrons source use $^7\rm Li$  as target for deuterons. Neutrons are emitted.
But what happens to protons?  Why they stay in the target?

Answer (score 1):

The protons get captured in lithium to form $^9$Be. It is than emits a neutron and $^8$Be decays into 2 $^4$He.

Comment: More precisely, the compound nucleus formed is Be-9, which emits a neutron and an alpha particle leaving an alpha. That Be8 decay is really fast with a high Q value.

Comment: I suspected, but only saw the $^7$Li(d,n)$^8$Be notation.

Comment: Yeah, the lifetime of 8Be is less than $10^{-16}$ seconds. The 7Li+p is usually written 7Li(p,a)a. Anyway, good answer.